# Using input to capture the remainder of the line

Tags: sas

I have some code where I am trying to save the first two words into their own variables, and everything after them into a third variable.  Is there an elegant way to do this with an input statement?

I know I could read the entire string into a single variable and then chop it up into the pieces that I need but is it possible with the `input` command?

```
data email_list;
  attrib word1 word2 everything_else length=$1000;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input word1 $
        word2 $
        everything_else $
        ;
datalines;
one two blah di blah
;
run;
```

The solution would have:

```
word1 = "one"
word2 = "two"
everything_else = "blah di blah"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with list input.  But, you can do it by switching up midstream:

```
data email_list;
  attrib word1 word2 everything_else length=$1000;
  infile datalines truncover;
  input word1 $
        word2 $ @;

  input everything_else $1000. ;
  put _all_;
datalines;
one two blah di blah
;
run;
```